# Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do hint: not have locally

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, version-control

Just to give you guys some context, I've created a new repo on Github. and made an empty repo using `git init` but did not clone Github's repo.

Moving on, there wasn't an `origin` remote so I created a new remote like so `git remote add new-remote <ssh link for Github's repo>` and pushed a few files to it using `git push new remote` but I always get this error....

```
! [rejected]        main -> main (fetch first)
```

error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:mohaCodes/test.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: Have you tried running `git fetch` first?

Comment: before what command exactly ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Updates+were+rejected+because+the+remote+contains+work+that+you+do+not+have+locally

Comment: `git push -f -u origin main`